# ko does not update binded controls if model is changed programmatically

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

My model looks something like this. This is a very multi-functional page and the model needs to be modified sometimes, when very specific elements are clicked, this is done using an ajax call. Then an update function updates this model with the result, see below. Unfortunately, the model updates, but the elements on the page stay the same :(

```
function viewModel(result,currentTheme) {
        var self = this;
        self.isBlankForm = ko.observable();
        self.snapEdit = ko.observable();
        self.snapEditSuccess = ko.observable();
        self.isMeNotified = ko.observable();
        self.isEmailSentToUser = ko.observable();
        self.fromEmailBox = ko.observable();
        self.subjectEmailBox = ko.observable();
        self.themeNames = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.themeChoice = ko.observable();
        self.bgColor = ko.observable();
        self.frmColor = ko.observable();
        self.txtColor = ko.observable();
        self.btnColor = ko.observable();
        self.btnTxtColor = ko.observable();
        self.appID = ko.observable();
        self.revID = ko.observable();
    }
    var vm = new viewModel();

function updateModel(result) {
    var currentTheme = result.payload.currTheme;
    vm.isBlankForm = !(result.payload.isBlankForm);
    vm.snapEdit = result.payload.emailText;
    vm.snapEditSuccess = result.payload.successBody;
    vm.isMeNotified = result.payload.isMeNotified;
    vm.isEmailSentToUser = result.payload.isEmailSentToUser;
    vm.fromEmailBox = result.payload.fromUserEmail;
    vm.subjectEmailBox = result.payload.emailSubject;
    vm.themeNames(result.payload.themeList);
    vm.themeChoice = result.payload.currTheme;

    vm.bgColor = result.payload.bgColor;
    vm.frmColor = result.payload.frmColor;
    vm.txtColor = result.payload.txtColor;
    vm.btnColor = result.payload.btnColor;
    vm.btnTxtColor = result.payload.btnTxtColor;
    vm.appID = result.payload.appID;
    vm.revID = result.payload.revID;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout observables are actually functions, and need to be updated by calling them like this:

```
function updateModel(result) {
    var currentTheme = result.payload.currTheme;
    vm.isBlankForm(!(result.payload.isBlankForm));
    vm.snapEdit(result.payload.emailText);
    vm.snapEditSuccess(result.payload.successBody);
    vm.isMeNotified(result.payload.isMeNotified);
    vm.isEmailSentToUser(result.payload.isEmailSentToUser);
    vm.fromEmailBox(result.payload.fromUserEmail);
    vm.subjectEmailBox(result.payload.emailSubject);
    vm.themeNames(result.payload.themeList);
    vm.themeChoice(result.payload.currTheme);

    vm.bgColor(result.payload.bgColor);
    vm.frmColor(result.payload.frmColor);
    vm.txtColor(result.payload.txtColor);
    vm.btnColor(result.payload.btnColor);
    vm.btnTxtColor(result.payload.btnTxtColor);
    vm.appID(result.payload.appID);
    vm.revID(result.payload.revID);
}
```

**Further Reading**

- [Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) : See the section, *Reading and writing observables*

Comment: Perfect, my form came to life! Thank you Mr. Unicorn.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use KO setters instead of declaring the properties. In KO, every observable behaves as a function. So, instead of

```
vm.fromEmailBox = result.payload.fromUserEmail;
```

You should use

```
vm.fromEmailBox(result.payload.fromUserEmail);
```